# Access denied when try to create Document Set with Full control over library and Site

Tags: permissions, access-denied, sharepoint-standard

I am having the **Full control** permission on the Site level and Library level.

**when I trying to create Document Set it will shows Access Denied error**.
But i can upload document inside Document Set.
Also this error shows when trying to upload in Document Library.

I can create Document Set if I am Site Collection Administrator.

**Note:** The Library and Site has Unique permission

The exact error message is "Sorry you don't have access to this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Content Organizer in my site collection.
Before 2 days, I was **set unique permission** on the **"Drop Off Library"**(which is used by Content Organizer). This causes the above issue.

**This issue can be resolved in 2 ways.**

- *You can give Permission on Drop Off Library to Everyone.*
- *Inherit the Site Permission.(In this case you must have all the list groups 
  in the site level)*

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue while working in one of the project. To resolve this, we did the following :

1. Go to **Site Settings**.
2. Click on **Master pages and page layouts** under **Web Designer Galleries**.
3. Click on **Library settings** from top ribbon.
4. Click on **Permissions for this document library** under **Permissions and Management.**
5. Check permissions for yourself, if you have none permission then provide yourself Read and try editing now.

Let me know if this helps. Don't forget to upvote and mark it as answer if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Abhishek. I followed your steps but no luck. I am having Full control permissions for Master Pages and Layouts folder.